# bash cut to variable and cd

Tags: bash

Hi i am having a really strange problem.
I am trying to run the following scrip as root:

```
loc=$(transmission-remote 192.168.1.74:9091 --auth=user:password -t$TORRENTID -i |sed -e '1d;$d;s/^ *//'|grep Location: |cut -s -d : -f2) 
cd "$loc"
```

But get the error messege :

```
cd: can't cd to  /leprechaun_tv-shows/download/
```

But i works if i create a new string:

```
hello= /leprechaun_tv-shows/download/ 
cd $hello
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to Brian's solution, if you still need `$loc` to be quoted in `cd "$loc"` because the path could contain any spaces, then just use `sed 's/^ *//g'` to trim any leading spaces in `$loc`, like this:

```
loc=$(transmission-remote 192.168.1.74:9091 --auth=user:password -t$TORRENTID -i |sed -e '1d;$d;s/^ *//'|grep Location: |cut -s -d : -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g') 
cd "$loc"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you quoting `"$loc"` ?

If `$loc` has a leading space, then quoting the variable expansion will pass the directory *with that leading space* as an argument.

e.g. cding to root in this fashion gives me:

```
 $ cd " /"
 cd: no such file or directory:  /
```

Just remove the quoting. e.g.

```
cd $loc
```

Comment: If there is an initial space, that's a problem with setting the value of `$loc`, not quoting it for `cd`. If there is a real space in the value of `$loc`, the quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you have some initial whitespace in `$loc`, you can trim it with bash's parameter expansion:

```
loc=$(transmission-remote 192.168.1.74:9091 --auth=user:password -t$TORRENTID -i |sed -e '1d;$d;s/^ *//'|grep Location: |cut -s -d : -f2) 
cd "${loc%% }"
```

Comment: Note that `${loc%% }` will only remove a single space from the end of the value. If you want to remove multiple spaces you can use bash's [extended patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching): `shopt -s extglob; cd "${loc%+( )}"`

Comment: You're right. I used `%%` specifically to get the longest match, but forgot to provide a pattern that would match more than a single character. (Also, I meant to use `##` to match leading spaces).